# I generate a 400 Response with Jersey but I dont get it returned

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to program a web service with java and jersey. Recently I noticed that sometimes, after creating an error 400 response, I dont get anything returned from server.

For example, with this function I get a 201 code without problems, but when I try to get the 400 response, I get stuck waiting for a response until I get a timeout.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public Response registerUser(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        RegistryData r = gson.fromJson(json, RegistryData.class);
        new RegisterValidator().validate(r);
        // new UserDao().addUser(new User(r));
        return Response.ok(gson.toJson(r), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).status(Status.CREATED).build();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("ERROR: BAD REQUEST").build();
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("ERROR: " + e.getMessage())
                .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

I'm using Tomcat 7, Java 7, Jersey 1.19 and I'm testing with Advanced Rest Client plugin for Chrome.

Comment: Can you say if it happens always when returning through JsonSyntaxException or ValidationException or happens with both?

Comment: Both of them get stuck. It doesn't seem to be Exception related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered similar issues with this plugin, seeing it "getting stuck" when the server responds with an error.

You could try an alternative client, such as curl (if you're on *nix), RestClient (http://code.fosshub.com/WizToolsorg-RESTClient/downloads), or other tools you can find online.

Comment: Nice to know. I used that plugin before but never saw that behavior. But then again, it's been a while ago :)

Comment: Tried another one and got the Response. Thanks!